# how to change the form.js titanium to display time

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How do I change the form.js code from titanium appcelerator 
https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/Forging-Titanium/tree/master/ep-010/Forms

to accept time?

I want to add a "time" field to my form (people select hours, minutes, am/pm). How can I do that by changing the titanium mobile form.js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a time picker, it is simply

```
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_TIME
});
```